# Multitasking techniques

Tags: directx, directx-11

I have 2 tasks that need to be performed:

One is synchronized with refresh rate via the `Present` call; does fancy graphics.

The other does a bunch of computations on a virtually infinite workload; does not need to be synchronous with the first task; really does not like being interrupted (encourages coarser workload granularity).

Is there a way to optimally use the GPU in this situation with DirectX?

Perhaps the solution would:

- issue `Dispatch` (or `Draw`) calls in a way that allows them to run/finish asynchronously.
- signal the current shader to stop.
- use hardware or driver scheduling.

Right now my soultion is to try and predict how long it would take to run the shaders, which is unreliable, unless I add a bunch of downtime...

*Trying to avoid the th**ad word as it means a different thing on GPUs*

Comment: I understand that even in DirectX12 calls from multiple queues are interleaved and are not executed in parallel, and there are no coroutine like suspension mechanisms based on queue priority. Could you elaborate why knowing how long the compute shader will take, actually helps you solve you problem, because I cant really understand?

Comment: The performance of the "heavy" shader drops dramatically, if it has to restart. Ideally, it would run for multiple frames. But otherwise, fitting a single call every frame will do. So the best thing to do here is to fit it exactly into the (otherwise) idle time.

Comment: If input lag is not a problem you could render multiple frames at a time? If not perhaps you could work on caching the results of the heavy shader so that performance doesn't drop as much. I don't see why the performance drop from being interrupted can't be got around. This would be a more robust solution

Comment: I'd also say that this is one case of the few cases where DirectX12 might actually be justified depending on how good you want the final result to be. One high priority queue for your render work, and another low priority queue that runs the heavy shader chopped up into little bits

Answer (score 1):

Create two separate D3D11 devices. Use one for the rendering, and another one (driven from another CPU thread with lower priority) for the computations.

Rework your low-priority computations making each Dispatch() to take a couple milliseconds of GPU time to complete. Don’t submit many compute calls at once: use 2 [queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11query) or a single [fence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_3/nn-d3d11_3-id3d11fence) to never dispatch more than 2 pending compute calls. Dispatch 2 calls initially, when the first is complete dispatch the 3-rd one, etc.

While 3D rendering on your main thread, lock an `std::mutex`, release once you rendered the scene before Present. On the background thread, lock that mutex when submitting more compute tasks, but keep it unlocked while waiting for a query or fence.

You still gonna have some interference between these two tasks, but it might be good enough for your use case.

Ideally, consider using [timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_query) queries to measure GPU time spent computing your background tasks. Then adjust size of the single task dynamically based on these numbers, this should allow to achieve ideal granularity of these tasks regardless on the GPU performance. Don’t forget to apply some rolling average over the last 5-10 completed tasks before using the number for these adjustments.